# .net this.Close() is not working as I want to

Tags: .net, window

Here is my partial code when I press button I want the current window to be closed and new window to open but the current window stays open

```
AdminWindow window = new AdminWindow();
window.ShowDialog();
this.Close();
```

if I only write `this.Close();`, the current window would be closed. How can I close the current window and open my `adminWindow` or why is this code not working?

Thanks.

Comment: ShowDialog() is a *blocking* call.  The next statement won't be executed until the user closes the dialog.  Simply swap the two statements.

Comment: Also, depending on the requirements, the OP could change the `window.ShowDialog()` in `window.Show()`, opening the new window without blocking and therefore reaching the `this.Close()` statement

Comment: Thanks it works! I got that show dialog is a blocking statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `this.Hide();` instead.